# How to prevent certain items from being added to the cart first in magento1

Tags: addtocart, ee-1.13.1.0

As for the title, I would like to disable the prioritization of certain items from being added to the cart In Magento 1.

For example, I want to treat a product with a price of 0 as not being able to put it in the cart, and put the product with a non-zero price first, followed by the product with a price of 0.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 0):

```
<controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>
    <observers>
        <aquait_aquait_name>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>Aquait_Aquait_Model_Observer</class>
            <method>checkfunction</method>
        </aquait_aquait_name>
    </observers>
</controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add>

public function checkfunction($observer) 
{
    if ($observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction()->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_add') {
        $productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        if (Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty') > 1) {
            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addNotice('The maximum quantity allowed for purchase is 1.');
            Mage::app()->getResponse()->setRedirect($product->getProductUrl());
        }
    }

}
```